# Flex : Reducing Print page size

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have used printjob in my project for printing. I have a stage with images, shapes and text etc in printing group. While printing, it takes some two to three minutes to getting print
a single page. The Print Spooler window shows that 60MB for each page.

Could any one help me to reduce this file size or how can i print without taking this long time.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your request page to a single image. It will then print very fast.